# Break an if/else statement if condition is not met

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a form I use php to process, it works except when a condition is not met. Instead of using a captia I hide a normal field. The process is only suppose to run if the hidden field is = to nothing. otherwise it is suppose to break. It works if $hide (hidden field) = nothing but it throws an error when the field is filled out.

```
<?php
$to      = 'test@test.com';
$email   = $_POST['email'];

$name  = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['comments'];
$hide = $_POST['message'];
$error=array();
if ($hide!=''){
    break;
}else{
    if($_POST['name']==''){
        $error[]="Your name is required";
    }
    if($_POST['email']==''){
        $error[]="Your email is required";
    }
    if($_POST['subject']==''){
        $error[]="Subject is required";
    }
    if($_POST['comments']==''){
        $error[]="Comments is required";
    }

    if(count($error)>0){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
        foreach($error as $data)
        {
            echo "<p>".$data."</p>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
        die();
    }

    $headers = 'From: Attorney Website'. '<'.$email.'>' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: '. $email . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>You message has been succesfully received. We will reply you soon.</div>";
        die();
    } else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Opps! Something went wrong. Please try again.</div>";
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to "break" *from* in that first `if` block?  If there's nothing to do in that block, just leave it empty.  Or, better yet, invert the condition (use `==` instead of `!=`) and have just a single conditional block, instead of putting all the logic in an `else` block.

Comment: `break` doesn't work with if statements, see the [documentation](http://php.net/break). Even if it did, your use of it (at least in your example) seems redundant anyway.

Comment: ok thanks, I will do that

Comment: you dont need to use break

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `break`

Replace:

```
if ($hide!=''){
    break;
}
else {
```

with just

```
if ($hide) {
   // run email code
```

this will ensure $hide contains something before continuing